# SQL about combine row values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question about a SQL statement for an existing database table:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME
```

gives a result with the columns: `id`, `lead_id`, `field_number` and `value`.

```
ID | LEAD_ID |  FIELD_NUMBER  | VALUE
 1 | 1       | 1              | yes
 2 | 1       | 2              | a@mail.com
 3 | 2       | 1              | yes
 4 | 2       | 2              | b@mail.com
 5 | 3       | 1              | no
 6 | 3       | 2              | c@mail.com
```

Is it possible to split the `value` column in two different columns?

**expected result:**

```
LEAD_ID | YES_OR_NO | EMAIL
      1 | yes       | a@mail.com
      2 | yes       | b@mail.com
      3 | no        | c@mail.com
```

I can't use the `MAX()` argument right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `SELF JOIN` and define the FIELD_NUMBER for each self join (if using more than just the two in the example).

```
SELECT t.LEAD_ID, t.value AS YES_OR_NO, sub.VALUE AS EMAIL
FROM TABLENAME t
INNER JOIN TABLENAME sub ON t.LEAD_ID = sub.LEAD_ID AND sub.FIELD_NUMBER !=1 
WHERE t.FIELD_NUMBER = 1
```

Output

```
LEAD_ID YES_OR_NO EMAIL
1       yes       a@mail.com
2       yes       b@mail.com
3       no        c@mail.com
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1587e3/3/0

Comment: Thanks, @Matt that did it for me!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a self join

```
  select a.LEAD_ID, a.VALUE  as YES_OR_NOT, b.VALUE as EMAIL 
  from TABLENAME a 
  inner  join TABLENAME b on a.LEAD_ID = b.LEAD_ID and b.field_number = 2
  where a.field_number = 1
```

Comment: Why did you put `b.field_number` in the ON clause, and `a.field_number` in the WHERE clause?

Comment: for force the a table with filter the yes or not rows and the same for b  table for filter the email rows

Comment: Right, but why not put both conditions in the WHERE clause?

Comment: is the same (is an inner join )    using the where or adding to the on clause in this case is the same .. .. I have choice this look for make more visible  ..  the separated  filter  ... but , i repeat, is the same  you can do  both way (for inner join)

Answer (score -1):

Like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEAD_ID
                , CASE WHEN FIELD_NUMBER = 1 THEN VALUE END AS 'YES_OR_NO'
                , CASE WHEN FIELD_NUMBER = 2 THEN VALUE END AS 'EMAIL'
  FROM TABLENAME
```

No Need for a self join